# MongoDB - Grafana distinct query

Tags: mongodb, grafana

I have a db called res and a collection called results.

I have used the Mongo plugin and configured it to connect to my mongo from Grafana.

Within Grafana, I have used `db.results.find()` and get a single result back (which is all I have for now)

However, I want to get a count of the number of documents.  In Mongo shell I would use `db.results.distinct('user').length` and get 1 back.
So I tried this in Grafana, and get just a really unhelpful 'bad query'

So I've confirmed the connection and confirmed the db.results.find() returns data, but cannlt figure out the syntax to get a distinct.  I had thought if it worked in shell it would work in Grafana, but guessing not.